# Eclipse plug-in editing

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I see a lot of articles for making new plugins, but not what I want to do. I've edited CVSProjectSetCapability and I now have a raw .java file. This is a pre-existing plugin within Eclipse already, and I don't want to play with the manifest or anything, just try to shoehorn it back in so I can debug. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: One way may be, edit jar file and add .class to jar and test. Take a backup of existing plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to go about it the hard way. Modifying an existing plugin is similar to working on a new plugin. Simply create a new workspace and import the project/source of the plugin in question. Make your changes and hit run. At that point you are running/debugging with your changes. When done, you can use PDE's export wizards to produce a new plugin jar.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see what you're saying, but I've never done this before so could you point me in the right direction as far as tutorials go? The main reason I wanted to avoid doing a new plugin was the manifest, I don't know what to do for dependencies and whatnot.

Comment: If you have an existing plugin, just find its complete source and will have the manifest along with all the other project metadata. As to plugin development tutorials, I don't really have a favorite. There are so many. Search "eclipse plugin development". Search on Amazon or your favorite online bookstore too as there are a few really good books out there that cover eclipse plugin development in a lot of depth.